# Emberjs IE8 Object expected error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, internet-explorer-8

I'm testing my app and while it works in Chrome, FF and Safari, it doesn't load in IE8. I see a blank screen and developer tools reports an error at the very beginning of the js file.
The error I get is

`Object expected at certilogo-f7ce...js at line 6 character 1`

First 6 lines of js file are:

```
"use strict";
/* jshint ignore:start */

/* jshint ignore:end */

define('certilogo/adapters/application', ['exports', 'ember-data', 'certilogo/config/environment'], function (exports, DS, ENV) {
```

6th line is the one starting with `define(....)`.

I'm using emberjs 1.13.9 and ember-data version 1.13.11
As per the docs emberjs version 1.13.x should support IE8. 
What's causing the error and what can I do to solve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, emberjs 1.13 should support IE8, but there are a couple of things that can cause it to break in IE8:

If it works in the development environment but not production, it's likely that you're using UglifyJS v2.7, which has dropped support for IE8. You can re-enable IE8 support by adding the following to ember-cli-build.js

```
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Force UglifyJS 2.7.0 + to support IE 8
    minifyJS: {
      options: {
        compress: { screw_ie8: false },
        mangle:   { screw_ie8: false },
        output:   { screw_ie8: false }
      }
    }
  });
```

This blog post explains it in more detail - 

[Getting Ember JS to work with Internet Explorer 8](https://www.bugmuncher.com/blog/ember-js-in-ie8/)

On the other hand, if IE8 is not working in the development environment, it's likely that a plugin is to blame. I know that ember-i18n breaks in IE8. Try removing your plugins one at a time and see if it fixes it.